# Error connecting to Windows Azure File Share

Tags: azure, azure-storage

I set up a new storage account in the Azure portal, created a file share and then hit the "connect" button in the interface.

```
net use l: \\sharename.file.core.windows.net\uploaded-images /username accessKey
```

I put in my key but had no luck:

```
System error 53 has occurred.
The network path was not found.
```

I checked my firewall and that wasn't the issue (on the outbound side).

Thanks,
John

Answer (score 0):

The syntax is

```
net use l: \\mystorageaccount.file.core.windows.net\sharename /USER:mystorageaccount mystorageaccountkey
```

so you should replace the share name by the storage account name just after "\\" and use the storage account name also as a username. The password is the storage account key.